# Gtk.TextView lost default cut-copy-paste signal handlers in a quickly project. How can get back?

Tags: application-development, quickly

I try to create a note taking app based on quickly. I have a Gtk.TextView what holds the note, and I need the default textview and edit behaviors what a Gtk.TextView has when I add from the code instead of in glade. I realized that the builder in quickly helpers connect all signals not assigned to a handler in glade to a default handler. This could come handy but in my case it is unwanted.
How can I get back the default behavior of the textview without modifying the builder function? I would like to keep the default handler functionality on other widgets.

EDIT:
In the meantime I realized that I lost only the default keybindig to those default actions, I mean e.g. ctrl+x for cut. The textview has a popupmenu and e.g. cutting from there still works.
How I can set ctrl+x, ctrl+c, ctrl+v to work again?

Answer (score 0):

its a bit late, but there's this nifty new TextEditor in the quickly.widgets (You need to seperately install them with apt-get)

Here is a blog post about it: http://theravingrick.blogspot.ch/2010/06/new-quickly-widget-text-editor.html

Good luck with it!